# Google calendar event description html in apple calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have created an event via the google calendar API.

In the description of the event I have added html code, which is shown fine in google calendar. In the apple calendar, which I have synced with my google account, the description ( shown as notes in apple calendar ) shows the content as raw HTML.

Is there a specific way to insert HTML in google calendar event in order to parse it from third party calendars?

I have searched online, but with no luck so far..

Comment: Have you visited [this SO post (Google Calendar API : event description in HTML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612010/google-calendar-api-event-description-in-html)?

Comment: Yeap. Google calendar event is a string, but google calendar parses the HTML (if there is any). Apple calendar does not. Also, this post is from 2012. I was just wondering if there is something I might have missed. Thanks for the comment though! :)

Comment: @manosagen did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: This is still a problem. And I'm sad about it. Google calendar iOS app will insert descriptions in plain text. Google calendar web client will add html-like tags for formatting and links, etc. Apple calendar (both iOS and Desktop apps) will not parse the html-like formatting in google calendar descriptions. Microsoft has the same problem not parsing google-html descriptions, and I think it's Apple's iCal protocol. So, really Google is the one messing things up.